# DDR4 Refresh VPP Power Consumption

Tags: power-consumption, ddr

My question may seem stupid but for a REFRESH operation on a single-rank DDR4 with multiple DRAM devices, how to properly estimate the DRAM power consumption ?

I tried to use Micron Power Calculator and I get a result for the  for one device. I don't know if I should multiply this value by the number of DRAM Devices, I heard of All-bank Refresh where refresh operations seem to be pipelined across banks. How does it work when there are multiple DRAM chips on the same DDR4 bus ? Does each chip start a REFRESH operation at the same time ? Then the total Refresh power consumption equals the value for a single chip multiplied by the number of DRAM Chips ?

Comment: Another question, what happens about the power consumption if one of the chip is doing some ECC work ? (then half the data bus pins are connected)